# Como passar dados de uma tabela para outra SQL

Tags: sql, vb.net, tabela-html

Estou com duvida para passar dados de uma tabela para outra:
Exemplo:

Tabela 1 ---> Tabela 2 ---> apagar todas as informações da Tabela 1

Estou criando o projeto em VB.NET e usando SQL

Answer (score 9):

Se a segunda tabela já existe use [`INSERT INTO SELECT`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp)

Caso as duas tabelas tenham os mesmos campos:

```
INSERT INTO table2
SELECT * FROM table1;
```

Se apenas alguns campos forem comuns, terá de indicar esses campos:

```
INSERT INTO table2
(column_name1, column_name2, ...)
SELECT column_name1, column_name2, ...
FROM table1;
```

***Nota:*** os nomes dos campos podem ser diferentes, têm é de ser do mesmo tipo. Eles serão preenchidos de acordo com a ordem em que são declarados.

Em ambos os casos pode ser utilizada a cláusula *WHERE*:

```
INSERT INTO table2
(column_name1, column_name2, ...)
SELECT column_name1, column_name2, ...
FROM table1
WHERE column_name1 = "a qualquer coisa";
```

Para apagar a tabela use:

```
DROP TABLE tabela1
```

Answer (score 1):

Basicamente, falando:

Cria uma tabela `tabela_2` baseada na `tabela_1`:

```
CREATE TABLE tabela_2 AS SELECT * FROM tabela_1
```

Deleta a tabela copiada.

```
DROP TABLE tabela_1
```

**Nota**: `chaves-primárias` e `chaves-estrangeiras` não são replicadas na `tabela_2`, caso existam na `tabela_1`. Nem mesmo o `AUTO_INCREMENT` é copiado.

## Atualização

É importante postar aqui que encontrei uma maneira melhor e mais adequada quanto ao problema de não poder copiar chaves primárias e estrangeiras.

Há uma forma de se fazer isso através do `LIKE`. Ao invés de apenas copiar a tabela, ignorando as chaves, ele literalmente copia a tabela, com chaves e tudos mais.

Veja:

```
CREATE TABLE tabela_3 LIKE tabela_1;
INSERT INTO tabela_3 SELECT * FROM tabela_1;
```

Nesse caso, executamos duas queries. Não é uma desvantagem, já que você terá as `keys` iguaizinhas da tabela original copiada.

Answer (score -2):

**Resolvido!**
Fiz um teste e conseguir transferir os dados de uma tabela para outra, mesmo com as chaves-primárias. 
Ex. se você tem uma tabela1 com os campos (colunas): **Id, Nome, Idade** e na tabela2 com os mesmos campos ou com campos diferentes, mas com os mesmos tipos de dados você faz o script dessa maneira:
*Criação das Tabelas*

```sql
CREATE TABLE tabela1(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Nome] [varchar](70) NULL,
    [Idade] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tabela1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE tabela2(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Descrição] [varchar](70) NULL,
    [Anos] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tabela2] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

*Exportando das da Tabela 1 para a Tabela 2*

```sql
insert into tabela2 (Nome, Idade) select Descrição, Anos from tabela1
```

Fazendo assim todos os dados da tabela1 serão transferidos para a tabela2, mesmo que os campos (colunas) tenham nomes diferentes.
**NOTA:** nesse caso você não precisa incluir o campo Id, pois ele é a chave primária e de AUTO_INCREMENT.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).