# Copiando tabela no MySQL

Tags: mysql

Preciso fazer uma cópia de uma tabela no MySQL para uma simulação, existe alguma função para isso? Como eu poderia fazer isso?

Comment: Use a versão trial do navicat, então dê um CTRL+C CTRL+V na tabela... E F2 para renomea-la...:v

Comment: Preciso que uma instrução do MySQL faça isso. Isso irá acontecer dentro de um sistema

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Se você quer criar uma nova tabela baseada em uma já existente, há uma forma bem simples de fazer:

```
CREATE TABLE nova_tabela SELECT * FROM tabela_a_copiar
```

Tem algumas observações quanto a o uso disso. Expliquei isso nessa pergunta:

[Como passar dados de uma tabela para outra SQL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/52800/como-passar-dados-de-uma-tabela-para-outra-sql/52801#52801)

#### [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d09ae/2)

## Atualização

Para poder copiar `auto_increment`, `primary keys` e afins, temos que utilizar o comando `CREATE table LIKE`

Veja como ficaria nesse caso:

```
CREATE TABLE nova_tabela LIKE tabela_a_copiar;
INSERT INTO nova_tabela SELECT * FROM tabela_a_copiar;
```

Comment: @KaduAmaral, muito obrigado por colaborar com a resposta! não conhecia o SQLFiddle

Comment: De nada Wallace, eu ia responder, mas quando voltei do SQLFiddle tu já tinha respondido, então só complementei. ;)

Comment: Wallace, notei que essa modelagem não torna o campo auto_increment como na tabela original: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ca482/2 Sabe como contornar isso?

Comment: Dê uma olhada nesse [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2cc07). Eu usei o `ALTER TABLE` em seguida :)

Comment: @KaduAmaral, depois de muito tempo, descobri uma maneira, sem ter que dar o `ALTER TABLE`. Veja a atualização.

Comment: Verdade Wallace, bacana. Não tem como votar de novo, senão o faria. rsrs :P

Comment: O que vale é a informação. Vai nos ajudar muito