# Gravar dados em uma tabela baseado e outras duas tabelas

Tags: sql

Olá! Sou novo em transact sql e gostaria e tenho a seguinte situação.
Tenho uma tabelaA que possue a lista de colunas de uma segunda tabelaB.
Isso mesmo! Na tabelaB os nomes das colunas são os mesmos armazenados na tabela A. Depois usaria as informações do SELECT na tabelaB e armazenaria em uma terceira tabelac. Seria algo do tipo:

```
@Coluna = SELECT nomecoluna FROM tabelaA;
WHILE (!@Coluna)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO TABLE tabelaC (data, tag) 
SELECT data, @Coluna from tabelaB;
END
```

Obs: A coluna tag na tabelaC receberia como valor o nome da coluna (@coluna)

Espero que alguém se anime a me ajudar! Abs!

Comment: Verifica se isso pode ser útil para você:https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/52800/como-passar-dados-de-uma-tabela-para-outra-sql?rq=1

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, mas esse exemplo ai é somente para inserir uma tabela em outra. Infelizmente estou precisando de algo bem mais complexo!

Answer (score 0):

Acho que assim funciona:

```
declare @query nvarchar(max), @nome varchar(50)
declare @temp Table (nomecoluna nvarchar(50))

--SALVE OS REGISTROS COM OS NOMES DAS COLUNAS EM @TABLE
insert into @temp
select * from TabelaA

--ENQUANTO EXISTIR REGISTRO EM @TABLE...
while exists (select nomecoluna from @temp)

begin
--...CRIA A QUERY PARA PEGAR DE UMA TABELA E INSERIR NA OUTRA
set @nome = (select top 1 nomecoluna from @temp);

set @query = 'insert into TabelaC (tag) select '+@nome+' from TabelaB';
--EXECUTE A QUERY
exec (@query)
--E APAGUE O REGISTRO DE @TEMP
delete from @temp where nomecoluna = @nome

end
```

Comment: Olá Leon. Pelo que entendi vc esta lendo os nomes da colunas da TabelaA e armazenando em uma tabela temporária. Depois lê dessa tabela e grava na TabelaC. No meu caso são mesmo 3 tabelas: 
TabelaA
  - nomecol
TabelaB
  -datahora
  -nomecol1
  -nomecol2
  -nomecol3
(*)Os nomes das colunas nessa tabela tem correspondentes na TabelaA
TabaleC
  -datahora
  -nomecoluna (recebe string 'nomecol1' ou 'nomecol2', ou 'nomecol3'
  -valor (recebe o valor que esta armazenado nas colunas nomecol1, nomecol2, etc)

Comment: Estou selecionando da TabelaB e inserindo na TabelaC.

Comment: A sim. Entendi. Vou testar aqui. Vlw!

Comment: Olá Leon. Fiz o teste aqui e o que está sendo inserido em tag na TabelaC é o valor e não o nome da coluna.

Comment: insert into TabelaC (tag) values ('''+@nome+''') . Assim vai inserir o nome da coluna.

Comment: Parece que é isso mesmo. O problema agora e como colocar aspas dentro de aspas. Estou usando o Management Studio e dá erro:
(5 row(s) affected)
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'tag1'.

(1 row(s) affected)
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'tag2'. Já tentei várias combinações de aspas simples e duplas e nada... :(

Comment: Acho que não tenho como colocar "into" no insert no script pq o insert esta baseado no select.

Comment: Funcionou! Eram 3 aspas simples! Vlw!

Answer (score 0):

Uma sugestão seria usar a instrução select into. Ele criará automaticamente a tabela após o *into* Precisaria renomear as tabelas já existentes.

```
SELECT colunaA, colunaB, coluna C 
INTO TabelaB
FROM TabelaA
WHERE ...

SELECT colunaA, colunaB, coluna C 
INTO TabelaC
FROM TabelaB
WHERE ...
```